# Which one is correct way for initializing module,controller in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Which one is correct way for initializing module,controller in angularJS

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('Ctrl1', Ctrl1);
myapp.controller('Ctrl2', Ctrl2);

Ctrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
Ctrl2.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function Ctrl1($scope, $http) {
}

function Ctrl2($scope, $http) {
}
```

or this way

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('Ctrl1', Ctrl1);

Ctrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function Ctrl1($scope, $http) {
}


myapp.controller('Ctrl2', Ctrl2);

Ctrl2.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function Ctrl2($scope, $http) {
}
```

or doing this way

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {} ]);

myapp.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {} ]);
```

I am confusing which way is correct and can you give give me the cirrect project structure of AngularJS frmawork
Any sample project for that in github always welcome

Some peoples says John Papa style which one correct way i mean most efficient way

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor can you give me a sample project on this if you have...

Comment: I do not have any open source projects which follows everything in the style guide as it is. There must be something in the github. I follow it in my project and started it by reading the doc and installing the sublime plugins mentioned in the doc. The guidelines are straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to write:

```
myapp.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $http) { 
});
```

And you should use **ngmin** to parse your code before minification. It will automatically wrap the controller callback in `['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {}]` to avoid minification problem.

If you use gulp, use gulp-ngmin.

Comment: can you give me small project if you have?I am new in Angular JS i want to get the structure also have any ..

Answer (score 0):

The second way should be the ideal way as because

1. It is easy to read.
2. Easy to maintain
3. Protected from minification by the injector.

Anyways all of them are correct.

But second way should be the best.

Also make sure that you wrap the code in the way to protect from variable name clashes:

```
(function(){
  'use strict'; //another best practice
  //then your code
 })()
```

Comment: can you give me a sample project to me whether you have?

Comment: @AraviS A very good explanation here: https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course5. Go through the slides as well

Answer (score 0):

Angular's $inject method, we can explicitly declare our dependencies. This one may give problem for every controller injection. Other than you can use.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: myapp.controller('Ctrl1', Ctrl1);
myapp.controller('Ctrl2', Ctrl2);

Ctrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
Ctrl2.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

Comment: you were inject method explicitly. So avoid like above

Comment: more details refer angular document